# Upload OTP(opentrip planner ) based Journey planner on cloudbees

Tags: java, upload, gis, cloudbees, opentripplanner

I have developed a journey planner app using opentripplanner (its a java based server). Now i want to put my server online using Cloudbees, but i don't know how I can achieve this. Kindly help me out in this matter.
Thanks.

Comment: You might want to give some more details. Is your app packaged as a `.war` file? Does it need a back end database. Etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [opentripplanner documentation](https://github.com/openplans/OpenTripPlanner/wiki/RunningTheWebappInTomcat) you can't deploy it on default tomcat container as this require some customization. So the simpler way for you is to embed a servlet container and run as a [Java application](http://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/ClickStack)

Comment: Thanks @nicolas de loof, i am not an expert in Java applications. Kindly let me know how can in embed a servlet container.